# Executar comando MySQL quando iniciar o sistema

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, bash

Outros comandos consegui executar quando dá Boot no SO normalmente dessas duas formas:

1 - Criando um arquivo `.sh` na pasta `/etc/init.d/` e colocar o comando dentro.

2 - Colocando no final do arquivo `/etc/rc.local` antes do `exit 0`.

Se eu executar o comando na linha normalmente, ele executa:

```
mysql -u usuario -psenha -Bse "USE intranet;set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';"
```

#### Edit:

Tentei uma outra alternativa que também não funcionou: criei um script .sh e tentei colocar na cron (`@reboot /home/user/script.sh`)

O quê estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "solução" que encontrei foi criar uma cron para executar a cada minuto esse comando. As outras alternativas não funcionaram (possivelmente por estar sendo executada antes do MySQL estar rodando).

Comment: Realmente voce pode estar tentando rodar antes do servidor estar ativo. A inicializacao do sistema segue uma ordem e essa ordem e controlada pelo **System V**, Consulte **[AQUI](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-handbook/unix-services.pt-br.html#sect.sysvinit)** para entender como funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique seu rc.local (se o script precisa ser rodado como root, você tem que usar o sudo manualmente para rodá-lo).

Garanta que o /etc/rc.local tenha permissão de execução e que o script também tenha permissão de execução:

```
$ ls -l /etc/rc.local
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13 Jun 29 16:29 /etc/rc.local
```

Garanta que o rc.local possui também o [shebang](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjj8rW7sLnWAhXCQ5AKHXopDE0QFggvMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpt.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FShebang&usg=AFQjCNE0ysmlCESoy4APbityDygT0g-lPQ):

```
$ cat /etc/rc.local | head -n1
#!/bin/bash
```

(No caso de você utilizar bash).

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 305 Sep 22 17:28 /etc/rc.local
e
#!/bin/sh -e

Comment: Colocando o comando dentro de um sh (com permissão de execução) e colocando esse sh no rc.local funciona?

Comment: Criei o arquivo sh com permissão de execução (chmod +x) e executei, funcionou corretamente (com warning, igual quando executando pela linha de comando)

Comment: Se eu criar esse mesmo arquivo na pasta /etc/init.d/ com essas permissões, parece que ele não executa.. mas se eu executar ele manualmente, funciona

Comment: Vc tentou colocar no rc.local?
`bash /caminho/script.sh`

Comment: Sim, coloquei no rc.local também como disse na pergunta e continuou não executando..

Answer (score 0):

No /etc/init.d, monte-o da seguinte forma

```
#!/bin/bash ou #!/bin/sh como achar melhor
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          (nome que vc deseja dar ao script)
# Required-Start:    $exemplo1 $exemplo3 $exemplo3 (aqui vc coloca quais serviços devem estar em execução antes do seu script ser rodado ou pode colocar $all para todos)
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: breve descrição
# Description:       Descrição completa
### END INIT INFO

#comando a ser executado

mysql -u usuario -psenha -Bse "USE intranet;set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';"
```

Cuidado ao usar aspas duplas, se tiver algum caracter especial, o mesmo será interpretado, antes de qualquer caracter especial coloque \ (barra invertida) para escape.

Torne o arquivo executável
chmod +x /etc/init.d/seu_script
Coloque na inicialização
update-rc.d seu_script defaults
update-rc.d seu_script enable
caso tenha interesse de uma olhada em http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/#contents

Usando rc.local da seguinte forma

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.

#Comando a ser executado
mysql -u usuario -psenha -Bse "USE intranet;set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';"
exit 0
```

Certifique-se de que o mesmo tenha permissão de execução,
verifica se o rc.local está na inicialização do sistema, caso não esteja coloque usando o seguinte comando

```
update-rc.d rc.local defaults
update-rc.d rc.local enable
```

Usando o cron

Crie um arquivo em /etc/cron.d/meu_cron e o edite da seguinte forma

```
*/1 * * * * root mysql -u usuario -psenha -Bse "USE intranet;set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';"
```

Certifique-se de que o cron esta sendo executado no boot do sistema, caso não esteja o coloque com o comando

```
update-rc.d <serviço> <ação>
```

veja mais em https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab